# strpos not evaluating to what I think it should

Tags: php, strpos

I am having problems with strpos evaluating properly.

```
$status = "L";
$x = strpos($status,'L');
echo var_export($x,true);
echo "<br/>";
if (strpos($status,'L') === true) {echo "L is there!.";}
else {echo "No L Found!";}
```

This outputs:

```
0
No L Found!
```

With how I understand strpos and the "===" vs the "==" this should be finding the L.

What do I not understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) doesn't return true, it returns false if the string isn't found or the index if it is found.

From the official docs:

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.

Comment: does that mean I need to use !== false instead of === true?  I always thought if it wasn't actually set to boolean "false" then anything compared to true would return true.  Is that not the case?

Comment: correct - though very short - answer. You might want to add a link or a quote of the docs. Or even explain why in this case also `true != 1`

Comment: @Jeff sure one moment, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You do need to perform a strict comparison. You just need to do the opposite one.

```
if (strpos($status, 'L') !== false) {
    echo "L is there!.";
} else {
    echo "No L Found!";
}
```

When evaluated with `=== true`, `strpos($status,'L')` would have to return a literal boolean `true`, not just a value that evaluates to true, and as you can see in the documentation, `strpos` will never return that.

If you used `== true` instead, it would work *sometimes*, only when L was not the first character in the string. When it is the first character, `strpos($status,'L')` will return `0`, which does not evaluate to `true`, but any other position in the string would return a positive integer, which does.

Since `false` is the value the function returns if the search string is not found, *the only reliable way to do this* is to do strict comparison against `false`.